# Select word next to symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery code on keypress 35 which is # to dropdown div. I need to get the word that is standing next to # e.g.

`<textarea></textarea>` And I type #Michael I want to store #Michael in `var name`
After making an ajax request to check if Michael exists in the database and if it does, echo it inside dropdown `div`. After what I click on some from the list and replace it with name and # before name like if I got result:

Michael Parker and click on this one  to replace this one with name value.

I need to select word that is typed with #

**[Q]** how to select the word that is standing next to #?

Comment: "After what I click on some from the list and replace it with name and # before name like if I got result:" this part of the question is not clear. Can you post the code and the error/behaviour of it?

Comment: I said on end its explanation for full work question is that I need to select only word next to # with # and make var name with that value.. Thats only what I need...

Comment: Can you post your code here to make it more clear?

Comment: Never mind if you dont know it like this you won't know it with code .... I'll ask on some other website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getName(){
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
  var name = t.split(' ');
  name.forEach(function(str){
    if(str[0] === '#') {
     return str;
    }
  });
}
```

I used this for test

```
<textarea>asjdaksdjans #hacj asdasd</textarea>
<button onclick="getName()">find</button>
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

**EDIT**

```
function getName(){
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
  if(t[t.length-1]=== ' '){
    var name = t.split(' ');
    name.forEach(function(str){
       if(str[0] === '#') {
       console.log(str);
       }
    });
  }
}
```

For test:

```
<textarea onkeyup="getName()">asjdaksdjans #hacj asdasd</textarea>
```

**EDIT**

```
jQuery(function($){
 $('textarea').on('keyup', function(event){
   var text = $(this).val();
   if(text[text.length-1]=== ' ') {
     var name = text.split(' ');
     $.each(name, function(i, str) {
       console.log(i, str);
       if(str[0] === "#") {
         alert('name is:' +str);
       }
     });
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: instead of return str, put a console statement `console.log(str)` and check the console.

Comment: It is working but I need to do it without button onkeyup every time till space

Comment: I think that is what I want just can you tell me what is wrong when I try to write it in jquery:

$('textarea').on('keyup',function(event){
var text = $(this).val();
if(text[text.length-1]=== ' '){
var name = text.split(' ');
$.each(name,function(str){
   
if(str[0] === "#"){

     alert('name is:' +str);
}
   });
   }
   });

Comment: @Careless check now, I have the latest EDIT with the jquery code

Comment: I will accept your answer but I put another question and Rory Mc ..... answered me what I needed :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110030/discussion-between-careless-and-amresh-venugopal).

Answer (score 0):

This is working example. Note that you cannot 'getvalue' from event handler. But you can call action from that handler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var capName = '';
            var capStart = false;
            $('#txt').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.key == '#') {
                    capStart = true;
                    capName = '';
                }
                if (capStart && /[a-z0-9_#-]/i.test(e.key)) {
                    capName += e.key;
                }
                if (capStart && !/[a-z0-9_#-]/i.test(e.key)) {
                    capStart = false;
                    doSomething(capName);
                }
            });
            function doSomething(text) {
                $('#result').html(capName);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea><br />
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```